# How can I pipe code and unit test to npm test?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, npm

I would like to unit test on the fly on my server without writing temporary files. Is there a way to pass both the code to be tested and the unit test to `npm test`?
The npm test documentation is kind of bare (https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/test).
Also, it doesn't have to be `npm test` if there is an alternative solution.

Thank you,
Jens

Comment: Sorry i did not get it. did you mean multiple test on single command ?

Comment: The aim is to provide a 'string' with the unit test and a 'string' with the code to be tested and then parse the results without generating temporary files.

Comment: The scope of code and unit tests are simple functions and tests not large scale projects.

Comment: Interesting idea. I've never seen a testing framework that supported this. They've all been file based. Write back here if you find one!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`npm test` is simply a convenient method to execute a `npm` package's test suite without having to worry about the details of how the suite should be run. If you run it on a project that has no `scripts` entry for `test`, you get `Error: no test specified`. If you setup a `package.json` with this:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo This is a test!"
   }
}
```

Then `npm test` will echo to the console `This is a test!`. What you do in a real project is set a script that launches the *real* testing tool. For instance, `mocha` is a test runner, so once it is installed, you could have:

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha"
   }
```

Or you could have Karma, or Jest, or tap, or what-have-you.

You wrote in the bounty notice:

> Some websites offer online testing for JavaScript code, are they really writing out temporary files with user code to test against unit tests with npm test?

The websites that offer online testing offer very different services. **So depending on which online testing service you are referring to, sometimes the answer is yes, sometimes no.**

- Travis-ci offers a service that runs your entire test on their server. To do so, it checks out the branch under test from a git repository so yes they are getting a copy of the user code. Note that this is quite independent of which test runner you've set `npm test` to run: whether you run Mocha or Karma, or some other thing, Travis checks out the branch under test and then runs `npm test`.
- SauceLabs and BrowserStack on the other hand don't run the suite themselves but provide virtual machines that launch browsers to test against. Your test suite still runs on a machine of yours. So they don't get a copy of the code being tested. Again, which runner you use does not matter. I've run suites using these services with Mocha, Karma, Behave, etc.

Focusing on your title now:

> How can I pipe code and unit test to npm test?

**No testing setup I know of *pipes* the code under test.** The most common method of providing the code under test, and the tests themselves is to **checkout code from a repository** like Travis does. (Note that this does not *require* you to make your code public. Testing services can work with private repositories.)

Comment: I am not planning to send my code for testing, I can run unit tests in my IDE. The last part is important to me. Is there no way to pipe or is it just not done?

Comment: I've used multiple different testing frameworks and don't know of any that provides any *specific support for piping tests and code.* So it would be fair to say "it's just not done". Now, it would be *possible* to pipe tests and code like you suggest, but I don't know of any *reason* to do it. Conversely, piping tests would create complications: either the test runner would have to become much more complicated, or the complexity would have to be passed on to the people writing the tests.